# Оплата за учебу по liqpay (ликпей)

Tags: javascript, php, joomla3

Может кто помочь реализовать простую форму для оплаты через Liqpay (ликпей)?
Сайт на joomla 3.9
Форма простейшая. Сумма оплаты и описание. Вопрос в том как отправить сумму введенную в форме и описание  на страницу оплаты liqpay?
Пример на сайте тут: https://www.unicast.net.ua/pay/

Answer (score 1):

Документация - [liqpay checkout api](https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/api/aquiring/checkout/doc)

Там же и пример формы, описание, action ссылка и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Страницу видел. Но я хз как передать значение суммы оплаты в data.

Comment: base64_encode.

Опять же, читайте документацию, если я правильно Вас понял
https://www.liqpay.ua/documentation/data_signature

Comment: может вы можете помочь с примером кода?

Comment: в чем именно..обработчика или формы ?

Comment: Вот моя форма https://nsi.nuwm.edu.ua/index.php?option=com_rsform&view=rsform&formId=4  Сделал ее через компонент RSForm pro. Дальше нужно при нажатии кнопки Оплатить чтоб перенапрявляло на страницу ликпей с уже введенной сумой. Как я понимаю нужен обработчик.

Comment: Я перешел, ввел сумму, меня редиректнуло на страницу оплаты и сумма там отображается автоматически..не совсем понимаю, чего Вы хотите добиться

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118249/discussion-between---and-podpisochka1288).

Comment: Можете скрин показать?